# How do I define functions in parent component and pass them to respective child components?

Tags: reactjs, forms

More of a two part question: I need to define each of the onChange handle functions in my parent component and pass them to respective child components. After that How would I  get the value of form elements in your parent component?

```
class App extends Component {

       render() {

    const handleChange = (data) =>

    {console.log(data)}

         return (

      <div className="App">

      <PageOne handleChange={handleChange} /> 
      <PageTwo />
      <PageThree />
      <PageFour />
      <PageFive />
      <PageSix />

      <Button onSubmit={this.props.handleChange()}>
         Submit Form
      </Button>

      <br/>
      <br/>



      </div>

        );
      }
     }



Page One Component 







          class PageOne extends Component {

      constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state={
         generalDetails: '',
          phoneNumber: '',
         fName: '',
         mName: '',
         lName: '',
         gender: '',


        }
       this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);


      }



 handleChange = (data) =>

{console.log(data)

}



     handleInputChange(event) {
       const target = event.target;
       const value = target.type === 'checkbox' ? target.checked : 
     target.value;
       const name = target.name;


       console.log(`Input name ${name}. Input value ${value}.`);

       this.setState({
         [name]: value
       });
     }




       render() {
         return (
           <div className="PageOneWrapper"
              style={{
               background: '#969fad'
           }}


      >
      <div className="Details">

      <h1>CareerTrackers Program Orientation</h1>
      <p> Please complete this form to ensure we have your most up-to-date contact details. </p>

      <Form>
  <TextArea
  onChange={this.handleInputChange}
  name="generalDetails"
  placeholder='General Details'
   style={{
  width: 500,
  minHeight: 50
  }}
  />
  </Form>
<br/>

<p style={{
  marginRight: 600

        <Input
      onChange={this.handleInputChange}
      name='fName'
       placeholder='First Name'
            />








  <Input
      onChange={this.handleInputChange}
      name='mName'

       placeholder='Middle Name'
       style={{
         marginLeft: 50,
         marginRight: 50
       }}
       />


       <Input
       onChange={this.handleInputChange}
       name='lName'
       placeholder='Last Name'
       />

       <br/><br/><br/>

      <p
      style={{
        display: "inline",
        marginRight: 480
      }}
    ><strong>Gender: </strong>


     </p>
     <select
     name='gender'
     onChange={this.handleInputChange}
     style={{
       display: "inline",
     }}
     >
     <option>Select Gender </option>
     <option>Male </option>
     <option>Female </option>
     <option>Other </option>
     </select>



       <br/><br/><br/>


       <p style={{
         marginRight: 600

       }}><strong>Email:</strong></p>

       <Input
       onChange={this.handleInputChange}
            name='email'
            placeholder='Email'
            style={{
              marginRight: 470,

            }}
            />
            <br/>
            <br/>
       <Input
            onChange={this.handleInputChange}

            name='confirmEmail'
            placeholder='Confirm Email'
            style={{
              marginRight: 470,

            }}
            />

            <br/>
            <br/>

            <p style={{
              marginRight: 540


            }}><strong>Phone Number:</strong></p>




       <Input
            onChange={this.handleInputChange}
            name='phoneNumber'
            placeholder='Phone Number'
            style={{
              marginRight:370,
            }}
            />





            <select
            onChange={this.handleInputChange}
            name='Mobile Type'
            style={{
              MarginRight: 5000
            }}

            >
            <option>Mobile Type</option>
            <option>Mobile</option>
            <option>Work</option>
            <option>Home</option>

            </select>




            <br/>
            <br/>



<br/><br/><br/>



</div>
  </div>

          );
       }
     }
        export default PageOne;
```

Answer (score 0):

I've summarized what you want.

- There are several pages for user inputs
- These pages are child of parent
- Submit button and submit function is defined in parent
- You want to put all input data in many pages into the submit function
- How can I do this?

If above is correct, and you've not considered about [React-Redux](https://react-redux.js.org/introduction/quick-start),
I highly recommend to try it.

> React Redux is the official React binding for Redux. It lets your React components read data from a Redux store, and dispatch actions to the store to update data.

It would help to handle your situation.

By using it, you can store your various data into **Redux store - it is central data storage**

Eg. you can save many inputs into Redux store in child component, and read values from Redux store in parent component.

Answer (score 0):

Here is sample code that will help you:

APP.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import PageOne from './PageOne';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state={
      generalDetails: 'Initial Text',
    }
    this.onContentChange = this.onContentChange.bind(this);
    this.onSubmitForm = this.onSubmitForm.bind(this);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{this.state.generalDetails}</h1>
        <PageOne handleChange={this.onContentChange} />
        <button onSubmit={this.onSubmitForm}>
          Submit Form
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }

  onSubmitForm(){
    //Perform all Required Logic on Form Submit
  }
  onContentChange(data){
    console.log('in onContentChange');
    console.log(data); 
    this.setState({
      ...this.state,
      generalDetails: data.generalDetails
    });
    console.log(this.state);
  }
}

export default App;
```

PageOne.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class PageOne extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state={
         generalDetails: ''
    }
    this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleInputChange(event) {
    const target = event.target;
    const value = target.type === 'checkbox' ? target.checked : 
  target.value;
    const name = target.name;
    console.log(`Input name ${name}. Input value ${value}.`);
    this.setState({
      ...this.state,
      [name]: value
    });
    if(this.props.handleChange){
      this.props.handleChange(this.state);
    }
  }

  render() {
    return <div>
      <textarea
            onChange={this.handleInputChange}
            name="generalDetails"
            placeholder='General Details'
            style={{
            width: 500,
            minHeight: 50
            }}
            />
    </div>
  }
}
export default PageOne;
```

I have added only one field as this is just sample code. You can updated code based on your requirements.

Comment: Just noticed with the input value which is stored its not picking up the last value and you have to type the next value to get the previous one. For example If I type the values "Hi" it will only show up as "H" and I will have to type a space to get the next value if this makes sense.

Comment: Try to use onBlur instead of change. That should solve your issue

Comment: Hmm Can't seem to be typing in any values now. Here is where I have used onBlur:

      <Form>
  <TextArea


  name="generalDetails"
  placeholder='General Details'
  value={this.state.generalDetails}
  onBlur={this.handleInputChange}
   style={{
  width: 500,
  minHeight: 50
  }}
  />
  </Form>
<br/>

Comment: Which component you are using for textarea? Bootstrap or material ?